# trouble with importing a local package

Tags: python, package

I'm gonna reorganize big chunk of my python code  as a package. I suppose this package will be held in same directory where the main code is located. So the whole structure looks as  follows:

```
project directory
\-mymod
  \-__init__.py  # totaly empty
  \-xsum.py      # with xsum function
\-main.py        # main program
```

Because it's just an example

```
#xsum.py
def xsum(a,b):
  "just xsum"
  return a+b
```

And inside the main.py:

```
#main.py
import mymod
print mymod.xsum.xsum(2,3)
```

Python returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print mymod.xsum.xsum(2,3)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xsum'
```

I've tried to add project directory and/or project directory/mymod to sys.path, but it doesn't help.

Comment: `import mymod.xsum` instead of `import mymod` in main.py. Or `from mymod import xsum` in ____init____.py, and you can then just `import mymod` in main.py.

Comment: @doukremt you are right, it works. But it is very weird. There is nothing like is in documentation. Why I should directly import module in `__init__.py`?

Comment: I guess this is so to prevent name conflicts. For example, you could have a function `xsum` in `__init__.py`, and then, how to tell if the name `mymodule.xsum` refers to this function, or instead to the file `xsum.py`? The thing to keep in mind is that, when you type `import mymodule`, what Python really imports is the set of names defined in `mymodule/__init__.py`. So, to keep things unambiguous, it is convenient to import all your module files into the `__init__.py` file of the module itself. This way, both `import mymod` or `import mymod.xsum` remain valid.

Comment: thank you @doukremt, it make sense. It seems this should be stated in python documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @doukremt (see discussion above) I have found very simple solution:
in `__init__.py` insert the code

```
import sys,os
for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
        if filename[-3:] != ".py" or filename == "__init__.py" : continue
        exec "from "+filename[:-3]+" import *"
```

it allows to import all names from all py files in current package in package name space. So usage is quite simple:

```
import mymod
mymod.xsum(2,3)
```

if you would like separate modules names in a different namespaces use  next code in `__init__.py`:
import sys,os

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
        if filename[-3:] != ".py" or filename == "__init__.py" : continue
        exec "import "+filename[:-3]
```

In this case you should specify submodule:

```
import mymod
mymod.xsum.xsum(2,3)
```

Finally, if you would like import just several files in your directory, make a list and import them:

```
import sys,os
__all__=["a","b","c","xsum"]
for filename in __all__:
        exec "import "+filename
```